# Substitute specific char sequence inside filenames

Tags: command-line, bash, awk, filename

A friend of mine grouped tons of files in this way on windows

[image]

After I made him switch to Ubuntu, files are no more ordered based on the number of exclamation marks in front, so I would like to know how would I be able to switch them following this rule:

- `1` for `!` and `!!`
- `0` for `!!!` and `!!!!`

I guess I should use awk but I am not an expert, therefore here I am..

Comment: Just curious, but did you manage?

Comment: @JacobVlijm Hi, we gave a quick shoot with GPRename, but it doesnt seem working on html files, we will come back on it soon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For batch renaming of files and directories with GUI you can use [GPRename](http://gprename.sourceforge.net/screenshot.php).

[image: GPRename]

You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install gprename
```

Comment: It looks perfect, I will try it

Answer (score 2):

In a python script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import shutil
import sys

dr = sys.argv[1]
replace = ["!", "!!", "!!!", "!!!!"]

for f in os.listdir(dr):
    test = [f.startswith(s) for s in replace]
    if test.count(True) > 2:
        shutil.move(dr+"/"+f, dr+"/"+"0"+f.replace("!", ""))
    elif 0 < test.count(True) < 3:
        shutil.move(dr+"/"+f, dr+"/"+"1"+f.replace("!", ""))
```

It will replace leading `!!!!` and `!!!` by `0`, and `!!` and `!` by `1`, assuming `!` occurs only at the beginning of the name.

#### To use it

1. paste the script into a empty file, save it as `rename.py`
2. Run it from a terminal window by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/rename.py '<directory>'
   ```

   where `<directory>` is the directory containing the files to rename.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the perl-based `rename` command e.g.

```
rename -vn -- 's/^!{1,2}(?!!)/0/' *
```

to match one or two `!` characters not followed by a `!` at the start (`^`) of the name, and **s**ubstitute `0`; and

```
rename -vn -- 's/^!{3,4}(?!!)/1/' *
```

to match three or four `!` characters not followed by a `!` at the start (`^`) of the name, and **s**ubstitute `1`.

NOTE: the `-n` switch allows you to do a 'dry run' without actually changing the names - test the expressions first and remove the `n` if you want to proceed.